# Post build events in Script#

Tags: c#, script#

I'm trying to create post build events to copy the final .js and .debug.js files for my script# projects into the proper directories. I can't use the regular output folder, since I have more than one project that references another project, and that always results in a build error (Unable to copy referenced script because it is being used by another process).

The problem is that the C# compiler appears to run the post build events BEFORE it writes the actual .js files, so they don't exist when the post build event happens.

Is there any other solution to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a DeploymentPath property in your csproj and the generated scripts will be copied there.

All of the logic is in here: https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/cc/src/Core/Build/Tasks/ScriptCompilerTask.cs ... so another option is to customize the build task to exactly your requirements.

The latest work if you check out the github repo, also has the script# part of the build process done during the build step of an msbuild project, so that should free up the post-build step for you to do what you'd like with the generated scripts. See https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/cc/src/Core/Build/ScriptSharp.targets. Again, its just msbuild stuff, so you could potentially customize the .targets file to your liking as well if it doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by adding the "copy" command as a pre build step on the projects that were using the script# project output, then adding a dependency so that the script# project would be built first.

Comment: That option doesn't seem to work reliably though....especially on build machines and with parallel build, etc.